# PHP check for existing entry in database

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to find if a username is already in a database. For some reason, $result returns false and I don't know why. I can put things into the database perfectly fine. I upload my code to the server using Fugu if that matters. I'm kind of new to php so any help would be great!

Here is the code where the query fails:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=baseuser' . $db_users_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users WHERE username='$username' GROUP BY username");
                $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

                if ($num_rows != 0) {
                  echo "username taken";
                }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use `PDO` with a function `mysql_query`. They don't work together. Use all functions `PDO` based if you go `PDO` way. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: why people so rude, I mean 6 down votes and no one cared to tell/suggest to improve the question

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper: Huh? Since when have downvotes to do with improving the question? Votes rate the question. And Downvotes are not rude, they are part of the same system that "rudely" asks for answers. Are you calling asking a question here rude as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PDO` like this, `PDO` and `mysql_*` functions not working together, you have to use them separately

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users 
WHERE username= :username GROUP BY username');
$sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0) {
   echo "username taken";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! worked perfectly. Only my 2nd day of php.

Comment: @AngelaChen If you are new programmer in `PHP` then I will advice you to keep using `PDO`, because it prevents `SQL Injection`.

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting to your table with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and then you try to query with the - deprecated - [mysql extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php). This cannot work.

Stick to [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), then [query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) with PDO, and you can even take it to the next level with a prepared statement.

Example:

```
$dbh = new PDO('seeyourcode');
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) 
        FROM users 
        WHERE username= :user 
        GROUP BY username";

// Prepare the statement
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':user', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// now execute
$sth->execute();

// fetch the result
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

`var_dump()` is just there to give you a feeling on how the object looks like. You can perform any action you desire witht the result there.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE :username) as `taken`');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($result['taken']){
    echo "username taken";
}

$stmt = null;
```

Also, you incorrectly used `PDO`. Check the [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php).

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it complex. Use simple connection method and use query **like this:**

```
$check_if_already = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uxxx where id = 1113");

$count_total_rows = mysql_num_rows($check_if_already);
echo $count_total_rows;

    if ($count_total_rows > 0) {
       echo "Not duplicate";
       //do your task here
    } else {
        echo 'Duplicate';
    }
```

Comment: **In addition** to this ^ answer: [`php_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`php_mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`php_pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.